# interval of convergence for series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

it seems to me that the series converges in all cases but ive tried showing this by the ratio test and that seems to make this really messy.  is there a better approach that ive missed out on

> find all values of x that make the series converge
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x}{n(1+x^2n)}$$

Comment: Is this a power series, and does the ratio test apply here?

Comment: It seems to you can not isolate the coefficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the estimate using AM-GM$$\left|\frac{x}{n(1+x^2n)}\right|=\frac1{n\left(\frac1{|x|}+|x|n\right)}\le\frac1{n\cdot2\sqrt{n}}=\frac1{2n^{3/2}},$$ which is valid even in the case $x=0,$ your series converges uniformly on the whole real line.